# bash - Error with getopts argument in histogram plot script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So this is my code so far (im new to bash so i know it might be messy):

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":cs:p:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        c)COUNT="hello";;
        s)NUM=$OPTARG;;
        p)CHAR="$OPTARG";;
        \?) exit 1;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

while read number value; do
    printf "%3d " $number
    if [ ! -z $COUNT ]; then
        printf "%5d " $value
    fi
    if [ $NUM ]; then
        for i in $(seq 1 {$value/$NUM}); do
            if [ ! -z $CHAR ]; then
                printf "%s" $CHAR
            else
                printf "#"
            fi
        done
    else
        for i in $(seq 1 $value); do
            if [ ! -z $CHAR ]; then
                printf "%s" $CHAR
            else
                printf "#"
            fi
        done
    fi
    printf "\n"
done <${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

So what this code does is takes in lines of input in the format of {line length, occurances} or {x, y} and the script will plot the data with the line length and also the histogram plot of '#' characters.

**FIRST PROBLEM:**

My getopts is working fine, except for the "-s NUM", in which it is outputting an error when trying to divide $value by $NUM (the input number to divide by). This is supposed to reduce the number of # characters printed using NUM as a scalar. 
I can run the command "./histoplot -c -p '$' textfile.txt" completely fine, it does what it needs to do. but when i run "./histoplot -s 3 textfile.txt" it outputs the error: *seq: invalid floating point argument: '{x/y}*

What can i do to make this work correctly?

**SECOND PROBLEM:**

So with the input file containing:

```
3 4
4 1
5 3
10 1
```

The output should be (for command "./histoplot -c [or any other option] [inputfile]":

```
  1    0
  2    0
  3    4 ####
  4    1 #
  5    3 ###
  6    0
  7    0
  8    0
  9    0
 10    1 #
```

however my output does not contain the lengths where there are 0 occurrences.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help guys, i really appreciate it!

**EDIT:**

The first problem has been SOLVED, that just leaves the SECOND PROBLEM. Anyone got any ideas? :)

Comment: ALSO, the number determined by $value/$NUM needs to be rounded DOWN so if it equates to 4.57, the number of characters printed will be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to your *1st problem* is because of

```
for i in $(seq 1 {$value/$NUM});
```

which is syntactically *incorrect*, as you are not using the variables in an arithmetic context, in `bash` using the operator `$((..))` with a C-style `for-loop` just do

```
for ((i=1; i<=$((value/NUM)); i++));
```

Also, `bash` does not do floating point arithmetic and it always rounds *down* to the lowest digit when used in integer division.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works fine! Does this automatically always round down? so like, x/y = 4.57 = 4?

Comment: @Swallows: Yup, refer my update, and you can confirm it manually yourself, on doing `echo $((7/4))` it produces `1`  for `1.75`

Comment: You're a legend, thanks for the assist! Any idea for problem 2? :)

Comment: @Swallows: Am not sure I get your `2nd logic`, perhaps you need to revisit your design again. No way the code is printing the output as you need in its existing form